# ORA-00904: Invalid identifier - Creating a simple table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a simple table, but I'm receiving error:

> ORA-00904 - invalid identifier

and I'm not sure why.  I don't see anything that could be causing the issue (using Oracle 11g Express):

```
CREATE TABLE Measurements(
  MeasureAmountID       SMALLINT        PRIMARY KEY,
  MeasurementDescription    VARCHAR(255),
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the comma at the end and try,

```
CREATE TABLE Measurements(
     MeasureAmountID     SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
     MeasurementDescription  VARCHAR(255)
     );
```